# ffmpeg -to with multiple inputs

Tags: ffmpeg, multiplexing

I'm trying to modify a script from [How to download portion of video with youtube-dl command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388148/551103)

I want to specify an ending timestamp with `-to` rather than the duration with `-t`. However it is not working.

Here's the ffmpeg command in question:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:08:50 -i 'https://stream_url_video' -to 00:12:30 -ss 00:08:50 -i 'https://stream_url_audio' -to 00:12:30 -ss 5 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a copy 'output.mp4'
```

The audio stops at the correct timestamp `00:12:30`, but the video continues playing for a total duration of `00:12:30`.

Can it be fixed?

The script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#Arguments: URL, Starting Timestamp -5 seconds, Ending Timestamp, video file name
set -x;
readarray -t urls <<< "$(yt-dlp -f bestvideo[ext=mp4][vcodec^=avc1]+140 --youtube-skip-dash-manifest -g "$1")"

ffmpeg -ss $2 -i "${urls[0]}" -to $3 -ss $2 -i "${urls[1]}" -to $3 -ss 5 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "${4}"
```

Comment: Did you try adding `-to 00:12:30` before the video `-i`?

Comment: @Destroy666 thanks!

Comment: Why have the final `-ss 5` in the script? In that position, after the `-i`'s I think it applies to the output, from the man page it "decodes but discards input until the timestamps reach position" - that sounds like it would skip an additional 5 seconds of (combined) input before writing any output...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider how the arguments in ffmpeg work. Arguments before `-i` apply to input(s) and after them they apply to output.

Your command lacked `-to` before the input:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:08:50 -to 00:12:30 -i 'https://stream_url_video'
```

Therefore the video stream wasn't cut in the proper place.

Comment: I actually tried this first but got some error that I couldn't read and so tried putting it after

Answer (score 0):

`-to` applies to the following `-i` input file.

so the correct script is

```bash
ffmpeg -ss $2 -to $3 -i "${urls[0]}" -ss $2 -to $3 -i "${urls[1]}" -ss 5 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "${4}"
```